# Sonata Admin add field from external table

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm currently working on a project that use a lot of relations.

Here is the database schema that I have to use :

[image: Database schema]

I want to have a single admin page (for example product) that can edit product table content but also product_name or product_description table content, the problem is that there is no ID on the product table to link those tables.

Do you have any idea on how to edit external table content from a single sonata admin page ?

I tried ModelType::class, sonata_type_collection but nothing work :/

Notes : I can't add an Bidirectional relationship because the guy that works on the database don't want to do this :/

Thanks for all !

Comment: Try with sonata_type_model :)

Comment: I don't know if this can work because I don't have an ID on the product table that I can use to link with the relationship

Comment: With sonata_type_model you can for example to create choice array of exist product_name, but here may be you need of this: 
`->add('something', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                    'by_reference'       => false,
                    'cascade_validation' => true
                ), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'admin_code' => 'app.admin.something.service'
                ))`
app.admin.something.service -> should be a admin service of your product_name for example!

Comment: Thanks but I have to create a field in the table to store this, but I can't :/

Answer (score 1):

Create service for admin service for product_name (for example). After that add field in your product admin like that:

```
->add('product_name', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'btn_add' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false), array('admin_code'=>'app.admin.product_name.service'))
```

If this not work for you, you have to create custom type..

Comment: INVALID MODE : s5a955bf2801bb_productName - type : sonata_type_collection - mapping : ... still some problem but i'm close to the end :)